# Why does instance.property.property not work in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a strong C++ background and I'm just starting to use C#.

In a test application I write the following construction (wf is an instance of a class that I just wrote myself):

```
wf.m_button = new Button();
wf.m_button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
```

But the compiler (Visual C# Express 2008, using .Net 3.5) gives me this error:

*'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'FlatStyle' and no extension method 'FlatStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

If I change the code to this:

```
Button button = new Button();
wf.m_button = button;
button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
```

This works.

Why is instance.property.property not allowed in C#, while in C++ you can easily write something like this:

```
myVariable->myDataMember->anotherDataMember = ...;
```

Comment: Let me guess: wf.m_button is not an instance of `Button'?

Comment: As the compiler says, it is `Control`.

Comment: No need to delete the question. It is valid and other people will assuredly make a similar mistake in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with property chaining.  You have declared m_button as a Control object, not a Button.  The Control class does not expose a FlatStyle property.  Even though you know that m_button is a Button under the covers, the compiler cannot determine that as you could assign *anything* to m_button that is an instance of a Control object or a descendant of the Control class.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @Ed's answer: you could just write

```
wf.m_button = new Button() { FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System };
```

as well.

Comment: Pfft, they still have me on .NET 2.0 at work and I don't do much C# at home =P

Comment: @Ed: .NET 2.0? I actually started with 3.5 :-)

Comment: Yup, 2.0 and VS 2005.  We are mainly a C++ group, we haven't upgraded yet (though we are told it will happen "soon").  I started on 1.1 (ugh, ArrayList)

Comment: Just switched to 4.0/VS 2010. VS 2005's IDE was considerably faster, so you shouldn't regret too much. :-P